# Cassandra nodes are continuously throwing this error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

I have 6 nodes Cassandra cluster where 3 are data nodes and 3 are seed nodes

they all are using Cassandra version 3.7

below are the exceptions which I am getting on data nodes :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to compute ceiling for max when histogram overflowed
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram.rawMean(EstimatedHistogram.java:231) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram.mean(EstimatedHistogram.java:220) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.StatsMetadata.getEstimatedDroppableTombstoneRatio(StatsMetadata.java:115) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.getEstimatedDroppableTombstoneRatio(SSTableReader.java:1829) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.worthDroppingTombstones(AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:387) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.getNextBackgroundSSTables(SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.java:99) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.getNextBackgroundTask(SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.java:183) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.getNextBackgroundTask(CompactionStrategyManager.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:258) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

below is  the output for nodetool cfhistograms

```
I have one keyspace with 4 tables below is the output of nodetool cfhistorgrams

ubuntu@ankur:~$ nodetool cfhistograms keyspace.tabelname
Column counts are larger than 1996099046, unable to calculate percentiles
keyspace.tabelenamehistograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%            20.00             29.52          14530.76              9887               NaN
75%            24.00             35.43          25109.16             88148               NaN
95%            24.00             42.51          36157.19           4866323               NaN
98%            24.00             51.01          52066.35          36157190               NaN
99%            24.00             61.21          52066.35         155469300               NaN
Min             2.00              6.87             61.22                61                 0
Max            24.00       10299432.64         268650.95       765256466109223372036854776000

ubuntu@ankur:~$ nodetool cfhistogramskeyspace.tablename
keyspace.tabelename histograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%             0.00             20.50              0.00               215                 8
75%             0.00             24.60              0.00               310                14
95%             0.00             29.52              0.00               446                24
98%             0.00             29.52              0.00               535                29
99%             0.00             35.43              0.00               535                29
Min             0.00              3.31              0.00                73                 0
Max             0.00       10299432.64              0.00           4055269            219342

ubuntu@ankur:~$ nodetool cfhistograms keyspace.tabelename
keyspace.tabelename histograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%            24.00             24.60           1629.72               446                24
75%            29.00             29.52           2816.16               535                29
95%            29.00             35.43           7007.51               924                50
98%            29.00             42.51          12108.97              1109                60
99%            29.00             42.51          14530.76              1331                86
Min             2.00              5.72             20.50                51                 0
Max            35.00       10299432.64         557074.61           4866323            654949

ubuntu@ankur:~$ nodetool cfhistograms keyspace.tabelename
keyspace.tabelename histograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%             0.00             14.24              0.00               124                 2
75%             0.00             17.08              0.00               149                 2
95%             0.00             24.60              0.00               215                 4
98%             0.00             24.60              0.00               372                 7
99%             0.00             29.52              0.00               535                12
Min             0.00              1.33              0.00                36                 0
Max             0.00       10299432.64              0.00           8409007            182785
```

Below is the table structure which we follow for all tables

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.tablename (
    xxxx uuid,
    xxxx timeuuid,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx uuid,
    xxxx text,
    city text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx timeuuid,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    convtype text,
    xxxx float,
    xxxx float,
    xxxx float,
    xxxx float,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx ascii,
    xxxx text,
    device text,
    eventxxxxaction text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx int,
    xxxx int,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx uuid,
    xxxx int,
    ip inet,
    xxxx float,
    xxxx int,
    xxxx uuid,
    xxxx float,
    xxxx boolean,
    xxxx uuid,
    xxxx text,
    params map<text, text>,
    referrer text,
    servicelist set<frozen<service_item>>,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    uxxxxseragent text,
    xxxx text,
    xxxx text,
    PRIMARY KEY (xxx)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Any leads or suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks
Ankur

Comment: Can you show the structures of your tables and the output of nodetool cfhistograms?

Comment: Added that in my question description
 can you please have look? @AlexTbk

Comment: can you add the table structure for the first table? my guess is that the data model is the cause for the issue.

Comment: @AlexTbk Added my table structure 
let me know if you need anything more

Comment: Its impossible to say anything about your table as you removed the column names. What is the primary key? Is it the uuid field?

Comment: yes primary key is uuid field @AlexTbk

Comment: "6 nodes Cassandra cluster where 3 are data nodes and 3 are seed nodes" - They are *all* data nodes.  The seed node designation doesn't really mean anything, other than a starting place for the new node to look for the cluster.

Comment: "765256466109223372036854776000" - This is my guess as to what's wrong.  Looks like there's just too much in that partition.  Also, 3.7 is like 3 years old.  TBH, I wouldn't run any version lower than 3.11.2.

Comment: @Aaron it was my guess as well, but if the uuid is really the partition key, shouldnt it actually be fine then? I think he is running into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11117 here . It is fixed in 3.10

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be your problem right here:

```
$ nodetool cfhistograms keyspace.tabelname
Column counts are larger than 1996099046, unable to calculate percentiles
keyspace.tabelenamehistograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%            20.00             29.52          14530.76              9887               NaN
75%            24.00             35.43          25109.16             88148               NaN
95%            24.00             42.51          36157.19           4866323               NaN
98%            24.00             51.01          52066.35          36157190               NaN
99%            24.00             61.21          52066.35         155469300               NaN
Min             2.00              6.87             61.22                61                 0
Max            24.00       10299432.64         268650.95       765256466109223372036854776000
```

There is too much data and too many cells in that max partition, causing its inability to be calculated.

While this should be fixed in [CASSANDRA-11117](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11117), if you upgrade to Cassandra 4.1, you can *denylist* this partition to ensure that it doesn't cause trouble in the cluster.